# Off state canvas is deleted

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I would like to make a simple javascript library that involves rotating, translating, and scaling the canvas. However, when I rotate the canvas, since the center of rotation is (0, 0), half of the content gets deleted. I would like to know how to not have it deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate to the center of the canvas first, rotate, and then translate back.

Note that inevitably (unless you also scale up the canvas) you will end up with some corners cut off.